# HTML5 : How to consume a .NET Web Service using Javascript ? (HTTP POST)

Tags: .net, web-services, html

Please help me with this. 
Im using HTML5 for the website, .NET Service(.asmx).
I have a method getText() which returns a string of text. 
How do I call it and display it on my html5 webpage?

.NET Webservice

```
getText(){
    return "Hello";
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sherlene, is there more you could show us? Perhaps something you've tried? Some code? Something to give the people here a place to start from?

Comment: I would like to add some code too. But Im new to this. I dont even know how to start.

Comment: Sherlene, you can click **edit** underneath the question and paste in relevant blocks of code that help clarify your question. Formatting might be tricky at first, but don't worry so much about that. We can help with that too.

Comment: getText() {
     return "Hello";
}

Comment: If you're talking about a SOAP web service, this usually isn't done on the client, as it requires making a POST to third-party domain with custom headers and stuff. I guess you could do it with CORS, in certain browsers, but it would be pretty unusual.

Comment: Is it possible to do it with HTTP POST instead of SOAP?

Comment: @SherleneTan depending on the web service configuration, it may allow posts without the special SOAPAction header. Check the WSDL and any docs you can find for the web service you're using.

Comment: Yes, it is. Just calling the webservice so I can get the returned value and display it on the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Dave Ward wrote a very helpful article which should walk you through the code to accomplish this exact scenario.

[Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Here's a basic example which will simply output the response from the server into a `<div>` tag.

```
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "PATH-TO-WEB-SERVICE.asmx/WEB-SERVICE-METHOD-NAME",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        $('#output').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would prefer using javascript as Im more experienced in it.

Comment: @SherleneTan who set up the web service? Someone within your organization? They should be able to tell you whether it supports JSON, or SOAP, or raw POSTs, or whatever. All we can do is guess.

Comment: Yep. Someone within my organization created the web service. Supports SOAP, HTTP GET, HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0):

First include the latest jquery libraray. Following is the simple ajax call to get the data from your asmx web service. The data type which i used is json. When your response from your service is succeeded than it call the 'SuccessFunc' function otherwise 'FailedFunc' is called.

```
function GetText() {
                try {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/YourService/YourService.asmx/GetText",
                        data: "{''}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: SucceedFunc,
                        dataType: "json",
                        failure: FailedFunc
                    });
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert('failed to call web service. Error: ' + e);
                }
            }
```

Failed function

```
function FailedFunc(error) {
     alert('error: ' + error);    
        }
```

Success Function

```
function SuccessFunc(responce) {
           alert(eval(responce.d));
        }
```

Comment: I copied exactly but I still cant get anything to display on my browser. I tried some troubleshooting. It didnt get to the SuccessFunc function nor the FailedFunc. Went into "try".

Comment: First of all check your web service url, just copy and paste your url on browser and check is it browsing? Let's say your url is http://localhost/YourService/YourService.asmx (in your case it might be different). Now look carefully the mentioned url in the above code, there is a function name 'GetText'. Put your function name here which you want to call....

Comment: Yep. I checked the URL. No problem with that.